# Unwanted typecast in foreach

Tags: php, foreach, casting

I am using a function to clean variables for security purposes. However, this function convert each value into a string datatype, which I don't want.

So in example, when the input parameter is a integer datatype, the function return a string datatype.

Any idea how to return the exact same datatype?

```
public function cleanInput($value)
{
    if (is_array($value))
    {
        $newVal = '';
        foreach($value as $field => $value)
        {
            $newVal[$field] = $this->link->real_escape_string($value);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $newVal = $this->link->real_escape_string(trim(htmlspecialchars($value)));
    }

    return $newVal;
}


  // In example
  $oldData = 20; // input is integer
  $newData = cleanInput($oldData); // output should still be integer
  if (is_int($newData))
  {
     echo "Working!";
  }
  else
  {
     echo "Not working...";
  }
```

Comment: Well, `htmlspecialchars()` does return a string, indeed. The function makes absolutely no sense when working with integers. Maybe `real_escape_string()` shows the same behavior. It is unclear what that method does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As arkascha said, htmlspecialchars and real_escape_string both return strings, it's kind of implied in the function of both.

If you want ints, floats ect ect to return with the original datatype you'll just need to not perform the cleaning on them. It doesn't really make sense to try to escape numeric types, anyway.

```
else if (!is_string($value))
{
    return $value;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php